# Given $[A,B]=0$ then $[A,f(B)]=0$

Tags: operator-theory, physics, quantum-mechanics

> Given $A$ and $B$ two operators that commute ($[A,B]=0$) then $A$ commutes with an arbitrary function of $B$

I recently saw this property of the commutators on a quantum mechanics course. We didn't get any proof on the property and we didn't get told wether this propery is true for any function $f(B)$ or if it needs to fulfil some conditions.

I've tried to prove it on my own but I have no idea on how to approach the problem as I haven't taken any course on operator theory.

I'd appreciate if anyone could prove this here and if anyone could tell me if this is true for any function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Care to take a guess what $$\cos\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&t&0\\0&0&t\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\right)$$ is? It is a good exercise in the basics, and try to take a guess without looking up what this means. How could you make this expression make sense?

Comment: I'd try rewriting the cosine in terms of exponentials where the exponent of a matrix makes sense

Comment: Why do you believe the exp of a matrix makes any more or less sense than the cosine of a matrix?

Comment: Because you do the taylor expansion of the function and then you get the exponent of the matrix on the numerator but i guess you could do the same with the taylor expansion of the cosine

Comment: Then, in the context of a physics class, do you suppose there is any reasonable assumption you can make about the functions you encounter? Can you now prove your theorem?

Comment: Of course $f$ needs some conditions even for $f(B)$ to be defined.  For example, $f$ is analytic on a neighborhood of $\sigma(B)$.  If $B$ is a normal operator, then $f(B)$ is defined for any Borel function bounded on $\sigma(B)$, from the spectral theorem.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I'm a second year student of both phyisics and math majors and as far as my experience goes, for many functions that we encounter in maths as counter examples for theorems are physically impossible. However, I don't really have an understanding on which functions make sense physically so I don't know what conditions they must have

Comment: This is true for polynomial functions, or even power series functions, but definitely not all functions.

Comment: A simple example which would not always work is $f(B)=CB,$ where $C$ is some matrix which does not commute with $A.$ You’d need: $CAB=CBA=ACB,$ which, when $B$ is invertible, would imply $CA=AC.$

Comment: An even simpler example is the constant function $f(B) \equiv C$, where $C$ is some matrix that does not commute with $A$ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fear that by asking this here instead of PSE, you are inviting people to overthink it. Almost certainly your context assumes $f(x)$ is well behaved, analytic, etc, and is assumed to amount to its Taylor expansion around the origin. So, by linearity of the commutator, you are supposed to prove that
*A* commutes with all monomials $B^n$.

You can prove this by induction, given the identity
$$
[A,BC]=[A,B]C + B[A,C].
$$
Now take $C=B^n$ and apply induction.

It's not meant to be rocket science; this is a routine identity you'll be using more than once a week.